# Precompute points in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

I wish to carry out a parameter sweep for a certain function in Manipulate, and create a plot for each parameter set.

Each plot of the function takes ~ 10 seconds, so I would like to precompute the plots for a table of parameter sets, then use manipulate to rapidly move between them. The Advanced Manipulate Functionality documentation has suggestions for slow computations, but does not say how to carry out this functionality.

Could you please help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: Compute the plots by mapping your function over a list of parameters. This will generate a list of plots ahead of time. Then use `Manipulate[listOfPlots[[i]], {i, 1, Length@listOfPlots, 1}]` to display the one you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working off the comment from @MarcoB, a working answer is as follows:
If you wanted to plot $x^2+b$ and manipulate b while following the above, you could use this:

```
listOfPlots = Table[Plot[x^2 + b, {x, -1, 1}], {b, 1, 9}]
Manipulate[listOfPlots[[i]], {i, 1, Length@listOfPlots, 1}]
```

Comment: +1 If you have `listOfPlots` on a separate input line and want to re-open the notebook and not have to re-run `listOfPlots`, including `SaveDefinitions -> True` in the `Manipulate` command will save potentially lots of time.

Comment: The first time I came across `SaveDefinitions -> True`, I thought, "Great!" and used it all the time. Then experience has taught me to avoid it. One can usually store data in better, transparent ways in which one controls what happens and when.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Very good to know! +1 for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

Some alternatives ideas. Plots, especially 3D plots, can be quite large. The list of plots below are around 165K. Some of the `Manipulate` cells that store the plots are around 670K. The one with plots in external file are 4-5K, but have to read the data in.   These sizes are not large enough to cause problems with the responsiveness of the front end. So it's mainly a question of style. Other advantages of some solutions: automatic initialization of the plots; persistent initialization (no re-initialization needed when Mathematica restarts); localization of variables; shareability.

#### Save in an external, shareable file

To share, send both the notebook and the file listOfPlots.mx.

```
DumpSave[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "listOfPlots.mx"}], 
  listOfPlots];

Manipulate[
 If[! ListQ[listOfPlots],
  Get[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "listOfPlots.mx"}]]
  ];
 listOfPlots[[i]],
 {i, 1, Length@LocalSymbol["listOfPlots"], 1}
 ]
```

#### Save in an external, local file

Must initialize the local symbol (once!) before `Manipulate` will work. One could use `CloudSymbol[]`, if one wants a cloud-based solution, which would make the list of plots accessible to other computers.

```
If[! ListQ[LocalSymbol["listOfPlots"]],
  LocalSymbol["listOfPlots"] = 
   Table[Plot[Cos[b x], {x, -1, 1}], {b, 1, 9}]
  ];

Manipulate[LocalSymbol["listOfPlots"][[i]],
 {i, 1, Length@LocalSymbol["listOfPlots"], 1}
 ]
```

#### Local file initialized in `Manipulate`

The initialization happens only once, after which the `Manipulate` operates smoothly. One can remove the local symbol first, to check initialization.

```
(*LocalSymbol["listOfPlots"]//Remove;*)

Manipulate[
 Dynamic[
  If[ListQ@LocalSymbol["listOfPlots"],
   LocalSymbol["listOfPlots"][[i]],
   "please wait"],
  SynchronousUpdating -> True],
 {i, 1, Length@LocalSymbol["listOfPlots"], 1},
 Initialization :> (
   If[! ListQ[LocalSymbol["listOfPlots"]],
     LocalSymbol["listOfPlots"] = 
      Table[Pause[1]; Plot[Cos[b x], {x, -1, 1}], {b, 1, 9}]
     ];),
 SynchronousInitialization -> False
 ]
```

Gussied up version, with a progress indicator.

```
Manipulate[
 Dynamic[
  If[ListQ@LocalSymbol["listOfPlots"],
   (*** MAIN BODY ***)
   LocalSymbol["listOfPlots"][[i]]
   (*** END  BODY ***)
   , If[! initializing,
    Button["Click to initialize plots",
     initializing = True;
     LocalSymbol["listOfPlots"] = 
       Table[
        Pause[1]; Plot[Cos[b x], {x, -1, 1}],
        {b, 1, 9}];
     initializing = False,
     Method -> "Queued"
     ],
    Dynamic@Column[{
       Row[{"Computing plot ", b}],
       ProgressIndicator[b/10.]
       }]
    ]],
  SynchronousUpdating -> True],
 (*** VAR DECLARATIONS ***)
 {i, 1, Length@LocalSymbol["listOfPlots"], 1},
 {{initializing, False}, None}, {b, None}
 ]
```

#### Plots stored in notebook in `Manipulate`

The variable `listOfPlots` is also localized in `Manipulate` and not a global variable (generally an advantage, unless you need the variable to be accessible both inside and outside `Manipulate`).

```
With[{listOfPlots0 = Table[Plot[Cos[b x], {x, -1, 1}], {b, 1, 9}]},
 Manipulate[listOfPlots[[i]],
  {i, 1, Length@listOfPlots, 1},
  {{listOfPlots, listOfPlots0}, None}]
 ]
```

One can use `Iconize`, if you "Evaluate in Place" (see Evaluation menu) to convert to an icon.

```
Manipulate[listOfPlots[[i]],
 {i, 1, Length@listOfPlots, 1},
 {{listOfPlots, Iconize@Table[Plot[Cos[b x], {x, -1, 1}], {b, 1, 9}]},
   None}]
```

> [image]

Comment: One can also store data in a notebook with `TaggingRules`. For instance, `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "listOfPlots"}] = Table[Pause[1]; Plot[Cos[b x], {x, -1, 1}], {b, 1, 9}]` to initialize and `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "listOfPlots"}]` to access.